# Out of memory when chaning orientation on activity showing an drawable

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

That's an onCreate method:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_foto);
    ImageView MyImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyCameraApp/TEMP.jpg" );
    MyImageView.setImageDrawable(d);}
```

So, I've tried to google it, and I found a lot of informaton on realeasing Bitmaps, but none about realeasing drawables from memmory. How to realease drawable from memmory, and where should I implement it: onPause or onDestroy?

Comment: add android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" to project's manifest file

Comment: @Khawar thats not going to solve his problem

Comment: @Khawar Yeah, that didn't work.

Comment: @IllegalArgument Any ideas what might work?

Comment: reduce the size of bitmap that you are getting. There are a lot of post on this topic in so

Comment: @IllegalArgument Do you mean, that I should create Bitmap object instead of drawable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting outofmemoryexception because your app is using(or needing) more memory than the granted. This usually happens while loading large bitmaps(images) in memory or showing many bitmaps. Have a look at [developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) for showing bitmaps efficiently. Use the following code to prevent OOM exception:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = getResizedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyCameraApp/TEMP.jpg"),3,3); 
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
// "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
return resizedBitmap;
```

}

Comment: Is it weird that it still crashes even if I use 3x3 bitmap? I can't get logcat logs, because my app tries to access external memory, and crashes before it reaches the point in the app where it shows this bitmap, because it's coinnected via cable.

Comment: the problems might be with permission write/read external storage. Also this path might be invalid  /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyCameraApp/ recommend  way would be Environment.getExternalStorage